# Error: ERROR: [wheel].whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. (Raspberry Pi 4 linux aarch64)

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install tensorflow on my Raspberry Pi and am facing an error that nobody has been able to resolve yet. I am getting the error mentioned in the Title when trying to install aarch64 wheels on aarch64. I'm following the guide at https://qengineering.eu/install-tensorflow-on-raspberry-64-os.html, as well as other guides, but with no luck.
For example,

```js
(env) raspberry@tars:~/TARS/io/dist $ sudo -H pip install tens
orflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.23.1-cp39-cp39-linux_aarch64.whl
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.23.1-cp39-cp39-linux_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
(env) raspberry@tars:~/TARS/io/dist $ uname -m
aarch64
```

I've also ran this:

```js
(env) raspberry@tars:~/TARS/io/dist $ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from distutils import util
>>> util.getplatform()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'distutils.util' has no attribute 'getplatform'
>>> import platform
>>> print(platform.platform())
Linux-6.1.21-v8+-aarch64-with-glibc2.31
```

I can't find anyone that has even attempted to use Tensorflow on raspberry pi within the past year or so. Is tensorflow on raspberry Pi just not possible to do anymore? If all support for Tensorflow on raspberry pi devices is gone, I will have to move on.

Any support is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Qengineering/TensorFlow-Raspberry-Pi_64-bit) are many wheels for different Linux distributions. Are you that your OS and C library version is matching to exact wheel?

Answer (score 0):

i've also had issues with this:

sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.23.1-cp39-cp39-linux_aarch64.whl
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.23.1-cp39-cp39-linux_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

it forces me to use the "looking indexes" which i tried to disobey with "--no-index"

Comment: no further development has been made, i need help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34562135)

Answer (score 0):

In short summary, your OS is likely not suitable or misconfigured. You might need to reinstall a 64-bit OS version for your Raspberry Pi 4.

Since I ran into the same issue, I did a short research and I've found an interesting guide here: https://qengineering.eu/install-pytorch-on-raspberry-pi-4.html, where I learned about this issue.

By following the instructions, I was able to identify that I'm using the 32-bit OS and. Here's the command you should run:

`getconf LONG_BIT`

You should see 64 as result. If it's 32, like it is for me, it means you should probably reinstall your OS on the Raspberry with a 64-bit version.

Additionally, your GCC needs to be properly configured. In my Raspberry (where aarch64 wheels do not work either), I see these flags when I try `gcc -v`

```
--enable-checking=release
--build=arm-linux-gnueabihf
--host=arm-linux-gnueabihf
--target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

According to the guide, one should see instead: ```
--target=aarch64-linux-gnu``, to be able to build packages / wheels / libraries properly.